# Django. Double-quoted string double-quoted second time

Tags: python-3.x, django-templates

I wrote this simple tags:

```
@register.simple_tag(name='is_active', takes_context=True)
def is_active(context, url_name):
    if reverse(url_name) == context.request.path:
        return 'class="active"'
    return ''
```

And in template:

```
 <li {% is_active 'home_page' %}>
```

On the development server it's rendered as follow:

```
<li class="active">
```

But on the production server with UWSGI it's rendered with duplicated double-quotes:

```
<li class=""active"">
```

**UPD:** Firebug render *&quot* as ".
Actually it's look like:

```
<li class="&quot;active&quot;">
```

Is it a bug in django test server?
How can I escape this transformation?

Answer (score 0):

From django documentation [simple tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags)

> Unlike other tag utilities, simple_tag passes its output through conditional_escape() if the template context is in autoescape mode, to ensure correct HTML and protect you from XSS vulnerabilities.
>
> If additional escaping is not desired, you will need to use mark_safe() if you are absolutely sure that your code does not contain XSS vulnerabilities. For building small HTML snippets, use of format_html() instead of mark_safe() is strongly recommended.

Code:

```
return format_html('class="active"')
```

UPD. This is not the bug in django, this is my mistake. I local develop in Django 1.8.7, but on the server django was updated to 1.9.2